# xcodeで開発していたcocos2dxのプロジェクトを、アンドロイド向けにビルドしたい

Tags: android, xcode, eclipse, cocos2d-x

xcodeで開発していたcocos2dxのプロジェクトを、 
windows環境でのeclipse(アンロイドアプリとして)でも実行しようとしているのですが、 
中々ビルドがうまくいきません。

始めにbuild_native.pyを実行して 
ビルドしようとしていたのですが上手くいかず、 
cocos compile -p android のコマンドを実行して 
ビルドしようとしたのですが上手くいきませんでした。

また、windowd内で、新規にcocos2dxプロジェクトを作成してビルドすると 
エラーが出ることもなくビルドが成功します。 
(※新規ではなくxcodeで開発していたものをアンドロイド向けにビルドしたい)

以下、cocos compile -p androidを実行した時のログです。 
エラー内容が推測できずどうしたらいいのかわからず困っています。 
なにかアドバイスや解決策などがあればよろしくお願いします。

```
Running command: compile 
Building mode: debug 
Android platform not specified, searching a default one... 
running: '"C:\Program Files\Android\sdk\tools\android" update project -t android-19 -p C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\myApp-master\proj.android' 

Updated project.properties 
Updated local.properties 
Updated file C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\myApp-master\proj.android\proguard-project.txt 
building native 
NDK build mode: debug 
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION: 4.8 
Ndk build failed!
```

【開発環境】 
android ndk ver r9d 
cocos2d-x 3.6 
eclipse  4.4 Luna 
apache-ant-1.9.6

【やったこと】 
・android.mkにcppを記入した 
・ヘッダファイルごとに#include "cocos2d.h"を記入した 
・ndk ver r10eでも試したが別のエラーが出た 
・新規にプロジェクトを作成したてビルドするとエラーは出ない

Comment: 同じエラーが出ましたが、原因がわからなかったので、cocos newで新たにプロジェクトを作成し、xcodeで新しいプロジェクトに古いプロジェクトを移植したところ解決しました。